# Apply distinct on single column from multiple return columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

My problem is I want to apply distinct key word on just one column in select statement. 
Here is my sql query.

```
SELECT ARM.AppId,
       ARM.AppFirstName,
       ARM.AppLastName,
       AQD.QualiId,
       VacQualiDetail.QualiName,
       VacQualiDetail.VacID,
       ARM.TotalExpYear,
       ARM.TotalExpMonth,
       VacQualiDetail.VacTitle,
       VacQualiDetail.DeptId,
       VacQualiDetail.CompId
  FROM tblAppResumeMaster ARM,
       tblAppQualificationDetail AQD,
       (SELECT VM.VacID,
               VM.VacTitle,
               VM.CompId,
               VM.DeptId,
               vcd.QualificationID,
               QM.QualiName,
               VM.RequiredExperience as Expe
          FROM tblVacancyCriteriaDetail VCD,
               tblVacancyMaster VM,
               tblQualificationMaster QM
         WHERE VCD.VacID = VM.VacID 
           AND VCD.QualificationID = QM.QualificationId) as VacQualiDetail
 WHERE AQD.AppId = arm.AppId 
   AND aqd.QualiId = VacQualiDetail.QualificationID
   AND ARM.TotalExpYear >= Expe
```

In this query, ARM.AppId is repeated and I want to apply distinct keyworld on ARM.AppId
How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: That SQL Formatting is against god.  Also, what DBMS is this for?

Comment: @Abe miessler. This DBMS is for HR web recruitment system which contains tables like tblAppResumeMaster,tblAppquealificationDetail and many more. I cant understand what are you taking about SQL formatting. I am novice in SQL .Please Guide me if I am wrong anywhere so that I can take precaution in future...

Comment: I down voted this question simply because I just spent a couple of minutes formatting that query in his duplicate post, only to learn upon trying to submit that the post had been deleted, as a duplicate of this one. I'm get a whiff of "serial forum pest" here. Some people just can't be learned ;-)

Comment: @Chirag: Abe means you have not formatted query in your question when you posted your question.

Comment: @Chirag: Abe's question `what DBMS is this for?` means `what is your database server?`

Answer (score 1):

example use 2 or more SELECT DISTICT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ARM.AppId, 
(SELECT DISTINCT ARM.AppFirstName) AS name
FROM ..............
```

if data database repeated,
according me the relation of each table is wrong.

please show the structure of the table

Answer (score -1):

```
select distinct ARM.AppId, ARM.AppFirstName .....
```

Comment: .. I have already tried this but it will give me distinct values if row formed by combination of all columns is unique but will not give me distinct ARM.AppId...

Comment: you are joining in a child table (vacancies) and then you try to get rid of it again? which one of the vacancies you want to select? or what is it in general that you want to know? This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891676/removing-duplicates-from-a-sql-query-not-just-use-distinct

Comment: .I want to select those Applicant who are eligible for particular vacancy. Here criteria is decided based on QualificationId and Expericnce. VacancyId and required QualiId are stored in VCD,and Applicant's qualifications are stored in AQD. Now I want those applicants whose any of QualificationId matches with QualificationIDs in VCD. I am using SQL SERVER 2008R2