# Don't select duplicates based on a column in a union query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which does an `UNION` :

```
select deal_id, codptf from acc_deals where run_id = 1
union 
select deal_id, codptf from acc_deals where run_id = 2
```

However, I find myself with this result :

```
AAAA;1234
AAAA;3456
BBBB;4569
```

There is a duplicate row, aka the rows 1 and 2 (same deal_id).

How can I exclude one of the duplicate rows ?

Comment: Oracle doesn't consider it a duplicate row as the values in `codptf` are different.  What do you really want from the query?

Comment: Which row do you want to keep? They are not duplicate rows, just rows containing a common value (deal_id).

Comment: which one you want remove? smaller codptf?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing duplicates from a SQL query (not just "use distinct")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891676/removing-duplicates-from-a-sql-query-not-just-use-distinct)

Answer (score 2):

it looks that you need **full outer join** here

```
create table test(id varchar2(10), val int, run_id int);


insert into test values('AAAA', 1234, 1);
insert into test values('BBBB', 4569, 1);
insert into test values('AAAA', 3456, 2);
insert into test values('CCCC', 1111, 2);


select
  nvl(t1.id, t2.id) as id, nvl(t1.val, t2.val) as val
from 
(select * from test where run_id = 1) t1
full join
(select * from test where run_id = 2) t2
  on t1.id = t2.id

    ID  VAL
1   AAAA    1234
2   CCCC    1111
3   BBBB    4569
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to @are's solution, you could do a group by instead:

```
create table test(id varchar2(10), val int, run_id int);

insert into test values('AAAA', 1234, 1);
insert into test values('BBBB', 4569, 1);
insert into test values('AAAA', 3456, 2);
insert into test values('CCCC', 1111, 2);
insert into test values('DDDD', 8958, 1);
insert into test values('DDDD', 2345, 2);

commit;

select id,
       max(val) max_val,
       min(val) min_val,
       max(val) keep (dense_rank first order by run_id) val_from_first_run_id,
       max(val) keep (dense_rank last order by run_id) val_from_last_run_id
from   test
where  run_id in (1, 2)
group by id;

ID            MAX_VAL    MIN_VAL VAL_FROM_FIRST_RUN_ID VAL_FROM_LAST_RUN_ID
---------- ---------- ---------- --------------------- --------------------
AAAA             3456       1234                  1234                 3456
BBBB             4569       4569                  4569                 4569
CCCC             1111       1111                  1111                 1111
DDDD             8958       2345                  8958                 2345
```

You'll note that there are several columns there - I've simply listed out a few of the options depending on which value you wanted to keep. It's up to you to decide which of the columns you're going to use, since you didn't specify which value you wanted displayed in the event of duplicates.