# SQL query: Exclude partial duplicates from query result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have data from multiple sensors. Each record has own id, sensor id, timestamp and measured value. Like this:

```
|--id--|--id_sensor--|-------timestamp-------|--value--|
    1          1       '2017-08-23 10:00:00'     30
    2          1       '2017-08-23 10:02:00'     30
    3          1       '2017-08-23 10:04:00'     31
    4          1       '2017-08-23 10:06:00'     31
    5          1       '2017-08-23 10:08:00'     32
    6          2       '2017-08-23 10:00:00'     24
    7          2       '2017-08-23 10:01:00'     24
    8          2       '2017-08-23 10:02:00'     24
    9          2       '2017-08-23 10:03:00'     24
    10         2       '2017-08-23 10:04:00'     24
    11         2       '2017-08-23 10:05:00'     24
    12         2       '2017-08-23 10:06:00'     25
```

I would like to exclude record if the value did not change so the result should look like this:

```
|--id--|--id_sensor--|-------timestamp-------|--value--|
    1          1       '2017-08-23 10:00:00'     30
    3          1       '2017-08-23 10:04:00'     31
    5          1       '2017-08-23 10:08:00'     32
    6          2       '2017-08-23 10:00:00'     24
    12         2       '2017-08-23 10:06:00'     25
```

I have to be compatible with sql server 2000 :-(
I would like to avoid using cursors if posible. Can anybody help?

Comment: Something like these should work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239169/how-to-select-records-without-duplicate-on-just-one-field-in-sql   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891676/removing-duplicates-from-a-sql-query-not-just-use-distinct

Comment: (1) What if values are repeated?  Say, Sensor 1 is 30, 30, 31, 31, 30, 30.  (2) Are you really using SQL Server 2000?  The time to upgrade was almost a decade ago.

Comment: I agree with Gordon, I cant use group by. I would like to upgrade but some customers are still running on 2000 :-(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following may be closer to what you really want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select top 1 t2.value
              from t t2
              where t2.sensor = t.sensor and
                    t2.timestamp < t.timestamp
              order by t2.timestamp desc
             ) as prev_value
      from t
     ) t
where prev_value is null or prev_value <> value;
```

You really should upgrade to a supported version of SQL Server.  Free versions are even available.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, that is pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
select your_table.* from your_table
join(
    select min(id) as mid from your_table group by value
) t
on your_table.id = t.mid
```

Comment: I guess you should group also by id_sensor